# Justifying text in C and general array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm attempting to fully justify (left and right columns line-up) input from files and this is what I came up with. The input files have embedded commands so from my pseudo output below I start justifying at the `company's` line and end at `telephone` As you can see it randomly joins two of the lines read together. Can someone please tell me why it's doing this? My input files definitely have newline characters in them since I double checked they were entered.

Also how do I do the following: Check if my read line will fit into my output array (of 40 char)? If it doesn't I want to move the overflowed string(s) into the next line or char(s) if it's easier. This one isn't as necessary as my first question but I would really like to make the output as nice as possible and I don't know how to restrict and carry overflow from read lines into the next output array.

```
Since it began to escape from AT&T's Bell Laboratories in
the early 1970's, the success of the UNIX
operating system has led to many different
versions: recipients of the (at that time free) UNIX system
code all began developing their own different
versions in their own different ways for use and sale.
    Universities, research
institutes, government bodies and computer
companies  all began using the powerful 
UNIX      system to develop many of the 
technologies  which today are part of a 
UNIX     system. Computer aided design, 
manufacturing  control systems,laboratorysimulations,even   the Internet itself, 
all  began life with and because of UNIX 
Today,  without UNIX systems, the Internewould         come to a screeching halt.
Most telephone calls could not be made,
electronic commerce would grind to a halt and
there would have never been "Jurassic Park"!
```

Below is my justify function that's passed the read file line using `fgets` in another function. The `printf` lines are just for debugging.

```c
void justify(char strin[]){

int i = 0;  //strin iterator 
int j = 0;  //out iterator

int endSpaces = LINE + 1 - strlen(strin);
int voids = countwords(strin) - 1;

printf("Voids: %d\n", voids);
printf("Input: %s", strin);

//No words in line, exit
if (voids <= 0)
    return;

//How many to add between words
int addEvenly = endSpaces/voids;
int addUnevenly = endSpaces % voids;

printf("space to distribute: %d  evenly: %d unevenly: %d\n", endSpaces, addEvenly, addUnevenly);

//Copy space left of array to output
while (strin[i] == ' '){
    outLine[j++] = ' ';
    i++;
}

//One word at a time
while (endSpaces > 0 || addUnevenly > 0){

    //Copy letters into out
    while (strin[i] != ' '){
        outLine[j] = strin[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }

    //Add the necessary spaces between words
    if (addEvenly > 0){
        for (int k = 0; k < addEvenly; k++){
            outLine[j++] = ' ';
        }
    }

    //Distribute to the left
    if (addUnevenly > 0){
        outLine[j++] = ' ';
        endSpaces--;
        addUnevenly--;
    }

    printf("Output: %s\n\n", outLine);
    endSpaces = endSpaces - addEvenly;

    //Finish copying rest of input to output when no more spaces to add
    if (endSpaces == 0 && addUnevenly == 0){
        while (strin[i] != '\0')
            outLine[j++] = strin[i++];

        printf("Output 2: %s\n", outLine);
    }
}
fprintf(out, "%s", outLine);
}
```

Comment: I created this for c++, but you can port the algorithm to C. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983008/how-to-print-justified-text-in-the-console-using-modern-c/22983009#22983009

Comment: Oh looks great, it'll take me a while to read, I'm very new to C coming over from Java. My biggest problem is pointers/arrays. @Flovdis

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to **center** your text (the whitespace left and right is the same for each line but not the entire text), **justify** (all lines begin and end in the same column, by inserting spaces between the words of each line), or **center justify** (which is both: each line is justified to the same length *and* there is the same amount of whitespace before and after each line)?

Comment: Sorry didn't know there was a difference between center justify and justify so I used them interchangeably. But I want to justify where the ends on both left and right are aligned and spaces are used between each word to fill up the line. @Jongware

Comment: @JohnatanJensen: yup - you want *full justified* text, which has nothing to do with "center". I clarified your post. (Can you tell I am a typesetter by profession? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On sunday I created a function (`justifyline()`) able to justify and indent a line you give it as input. It outputs a buffer containing the justified (formatted) text and any eventual text-remainder; such a remainder may be used as input to the function `justifyline()`.

After this step I've used the file below (text.txt) to test the behaviour of such a function. That test demonstrates me the need to use also word wrapping between lines. Then I've written the function `formatLineByLine()`. The function `formatLineByLine()` doesn't care of void lines.

Text file (text.txt): (I used the text in your question trying to correct it, but not all I've corrected, then the input file suffers of this fact!)

```
Since it began to escape from AT&T's
Bell Laboratories in the early 1970's,
the success of the UNIX operating system
has led to many different versions:
recipients of the (at that time free)
UNIX system code all began developing
their own different versions in their
own different ways for use and sale.

Universities, research institutes,
government bodies and computer companies
all began using the powerful UNIX system
to develop many of the technologies which
today are part of a UNIX system.

Computer aided design, manufacturing
control systems, laboratory simulations,
even the Internet itself, all began life
with and because of UNIX Today, without
UNIX systems, the Internet would come to a
screeching halt. Most telephone calls
could not be made, electronic commerce
would grind to a halt and there would
have never been "Jurassic Park"!
```

The output of the function `formatLineByLine()`

```
ABCDE12345678901234567890123456789012345
     Since  it  began  to  escape   from
     AT&T's  Bell  Laboratories  in  the
     early  1970's,  the  success of the
     UNIX  operating  system  has led to
     many different versions: recipients
     of  the  (at  that  time free) UNIX
     system  code  all  began developing
     their  own  different  versions  in
     their  own  different  ways for use
     and  sale.  Universities,  research
     institutes,  government  bodies and
     computer companies all began  using
     the powerful UNIX system to develop
     many  of  the  technologies   which
     today are  part of  a UNIX  system.
     Computer       aided        design,
     manufacturing   control    systems,
     laboratory  simulations,  even  the
     Internet  itself,  all  began  life
     with  and  because  of  UNIX Today,
     without UNIX systems, the  Internet
     would  come  to  a screeching halt.
     Most telephone  calls could  not be
     made,  electronic  commerce   would
     grind  to  a  halt  and there would
     have never been "Jurassic Park"!
```

Another step is the idea to use a paragraph per paragraph  justifycation. Then I've written the function `justifyParagraph()`. The function `formatInParagraphs()` reads the file text.txt and prints it justified using the function `justifyParagraph()`.

The output of the function `formatInParagraphs()`

```
ABCDE12345678901234567890123456789012345
          Since it began to escape  from
     AT&T's  Bell  Laboratories  in  the
     early  1970's,  the  success of the
     UNIX  operating  system  has led to
     many different versions: recipients
     of  the  (at  that  time free) UNIX
     system  code  all  began developing
     their  own  different  versions  in
     their  own  different  ways for use
     and sale.                          

          Universities,         research
     institutes,  government  bodies and
     computer companies all began  using
     the powerful UNIX system to develop
     many  of  the  technologies   which
     today are part of a UNIX system.   

          Computer     aided     design,
     manufacturing   control    systems,
     laboratory  simulations,  even  the
     Internet  itself,  all  began  life
     with  and  because  of  UNIX Today,
     without UNIX systems, the  Internet
     would  come  to  a screeching halt.
     Most telephone  calls could  not be
     made,  electronic  commerce   would
     grind  to  a  halt  and there would
     have never been "Jurassic Park"!
```

The function `justifyline()` is able to create a justified buffer with indentation (parameter `size_t indent`) and to use also a single space between the words (parameter `int nospacing` sent as 1).

The function `justifyParagraph()` is able to create a justified buffer with line indentation (parameter: `size_t indent`) and 1st line indentation (parameter: `size_t indentstart`). The formatted output may be directly printed when a NULL output buffer is sent to the function (parameter `char **outbuf` sent as NULL). The last line the function generates may be justified or not (parameter: `int notFrmtLast` sent as 1).

Both justification functions, when the parameter `char **outbuf` points a NULL pointer ( *outbuf == NULL ),  allocate memory using `malloc()` . In this case you have to free the buffer after its use. If this parameter is passed as  NULL to the function `justifyParagraph()`, the function prints the elaborated output, if `outbuf` is passed as NULL to the function `justifyline()`, the function returns an error.

The code is below. An issue of this code is that, in some cases, the length of the string should be computed using a function different from `strlen()`. To avoid this problem you may use these functions with lines that have a single space between the words. Such a problem affects the functions `justifyParagraph()` and `formatLineByLine()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int justifyLine(char *inbuf, char **outbuf, size_t linelen, char ** endptr, size_t indent, int nospacing);
int justifyParagraph(char *inbuf,char **outbuf,size_t linelen,size_t indentstart,size_t indent,int notFmtLast);

int formatLineByLine(FILE *f, size_t linelen,size_t indent, int notFrmtLast);
int formatInParagraphs(FILE *f, size_t linelen,size_t indentstart,size_t indent, int notFrmtLast);

int justifyParagraph(char *inbuf,char **outbuf,size_t linelen,size_t indentstart,size_t indent,int notFmtLast)
{
    char *optr=NULL,*endp=NULL;
    size_t len,s;
    int retval,nf;

    for(;;) { //Error control loop
        if (inbuf==NULL) {
            retval=0x10;break;
        }

        if (indent+indentstart>linelen) {
            retval=0x20;break;
        }

        if (outbuf!=NULL) {
            if (*outbuf==NULL) {
                if ( (*outbuf=malloc(linelen+1))==NULL ){
                    retval=0x30;break;
                }
            }

            optr=*outbuf;
        }

        endp=inbuf;
        indent+=indentstart;
        len=linelen-indent;
        s=indentstart;nf=0;
        while( *endp!=0) {
            if (notFmtLast && strlen(endp)<linelen-indent)
                nf=1;
            if ( (retval=justifyLine(endp,&optr,linelen,&endp,
                                     indent,nf)) ) {
                retval|=0x40;break;
            }
            if (outbuf!=NULL) {
                optr+=strlen(optr);
                *optr++='\n';
                *optr=0;
            } else {
                puts(optr);
            }
            indent-=s;
            len+=s;
            s=0;
        }

        break;  //Close error ctrl loop!
    }

    if (outbuf==NULL && optr!=NULL)
        free(optr);

    return retval;
}

int justifyLine(char *inbuf,char **outbuf,size_t linelen, char ** endptr,size_t indent,int nospacing)
{
    size_t textlen,tmp;
    size_t spctoadd,spcodd,spcin;
    size_t timetoodd;
    size_t ibidx,obidx,k,wc;

    char * endp;
    char * outb=NULL;

    int retval=0;

    for(;;) { //Error control loop
        endp=inbuf;

        if (inbuf==NULL) {
            retval=1;break;
        }

        if (indent>linelen) {
            retval=2;break;
        }

        if (outbuf==NULL) {
            retval=3;break;
        }

        if (*outbuf==NULL) {
            if ( (*outbuf=malloc(linelen+1))==NULL ){
                retval=4;break;
            }
        }

        outb=*outbuf;

        //Leave right spaces
        while(*inbuf==' ')
            inbuf++;

        if (*inbuf==0) {
            endp=inbuf;
            *outb=0;
            break;  //exit from error loop without error!
        }

        linelen-=indent;

        //Count words and the minimum number of characters
        ibidx=0;
        wc=0;textlen=0;k=1;endp=NULL;
        while ( *(inbuf+ibidx)!=0 ) {
            if (*(inbuf+ibidx)==' ') {
                ibidx++;continue;
            }
            //There's a char!
            k=ibidx;    //last word start
            tmp=textlen;
            wc++;textlen++; //add the space after the words
            //textlen<linelen because textlen contains also the space after the word
//            while(textlen<=linelen && *(inbuf+ibidx)!=' ' && *(inbuf+ibidx) ) {
            while(*(inbuf+ibidx)!=' ' && *(inbuf+ibidx) ) {
                textlen++;ibidx++;
            }

            if (textlen>linelen+1) {                    
                endp=inbuf+k;
                textlen=tmp;
                wc--;
                break;
            }
        }

        textlen=textlen-wc;

        if (endp==NULL) {
            endp=inbuf+ibidx;
        }

        if (textlen<2) {
            *outb=0;
            break;  //exit from error loop without error!
        }

        //Prepare outbuf
        memset(outb,' ',linelen+indent);
        *(outb+linelen+indent)=0;

        ibidx=0;
        obidx=indent;
        if (wc>1) {
            if (!nospacing) {
                //The odds are max in number == wc-2
                spctoadd=linelen-textlen;
            } else {
                spctoadd=wc-1;
            }

            spcin=spctoadd/(wc-1);
            spcodd=spctoadd % (wc-1);
            if (spcodd)
                timetoodd=(wc-1)/spcodd;

            k=timetoodd;
            while(spctoadd) {
                while(*(inbuf+ibidx)!=' ') {
                    *(outb+obidx++)=*(inbuf+ibidx++);
                }
                obidx+=spcin;spctoadd-=spcin;
                if (spcodd && !(--k)) {
                    k=timetoodd;
                    spcodd--;
                    spctoadd--;
                    obidx++;
                }
                while(*(inbuf+ ++ibidx)==' ');
            }
        }

        while(*(outb+obidx) && *(inbuf+ibidx) && *(inbuf+ibidx)!=' ')
            *(outb+obidx++)=*(inbuf+ibidx++);

        //There're words longer then the line!!!
        if (*(inbuf+ibidx) && *(inbuf+ibidx)!=' ')
            endp=inbuf+ibidx;

        break;  //Terminate error ctrl loop.
    }

    if (endptr!=NULL)
        *endptr=endp;

    return retval;
}

int formatLineByLine(FILE *f, size_t linelen,size_t indent, int notFrmtLast)
{
    char text[250],*app;
    //justifyLine allocates memory for the line if the outbuf (optr) value is NULL
    char * optr=NULL;
    size_t j,k;

    //print a ruler
    for(j=0;j<indent;j++)
        printf("%c",'A'+(char)j);

    for(j=1;j<=linelen-indent;j++)
        printf("%c",'0'+(char)(j%10));
    printf("\n");

    //starts printing
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
    j=0;
    while(fgets(text+j,sizeof(text)-j,f)) {
        if ( (app=strrchr(text+j,'\n')) ) {
            *app=0;
        }

        k=strlen(text);
        if (strlen(text)<linelen-indent) {
            if (!*(text+k) && *(text+k-1)!=' ') {
                *(text+k++)=' ';
                *(text+k)=0;
            }
            j=k;
            continue;
        }

        app=text;
        do {
            //justifyLine allocates memory for the line if the outbuf (optr) value is NULL
            if ( justifyLine(app,&optr,linelen,&app,indent,0) ) {
                if (optr!=NULL)
                    free(optr);
                return 1;
            }
            printf("%s\n",optr);
            j=(*app!=0)?strlen(app):0;
        } while(j>linelen-indent);

        if (j) {
            strcpy(text,app);
            *(text+j++)=' ';
            *(text+j)=0;
        }
    }

    if (*text!=0 && j) {
        if ( justifyLine(text,&optr,linelen,NULL,indent,notFrmtLast) )
        {
            if (optr!=NULL)
                free(optr);
            return 2;
        }

        printf("%s\n",optr);
    }

    //justifyLine allocates memory for the line if the outbuf value is NULL
    if (optr!=NULL)
        free(optr);

    return 0;
}

int formatInParagraphs(FILE *f, size_t linelen,size_t indentstart,size_t indent, int notFrmtLast)
{
    char text[1024], *app;

    //To uncomment when you use the commented justifyParagraph line.
    //see below
    //char *outbuf=NULL;

    size_t j;

    //print a ruler
    for(j=0;j<indent;j++)
        printf("%c",'A'+(char)j);

    for(j=1;j<=linelen-indent;j++)
        printf("%c",'0'+(char)(j%10));
    printf("\n");

    //starts printing
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);

    j=0;
    while(fgets(text+j,sizeof(text),f)) {
        if ( (app=strrchr(text+j,'\n')) ) {
            *app++=' ';*app=0;
        }

        if ( *(text+j)==' ' && !*(text+j+1) ) {
            //The following commented line allocates memory creating a paragraph buffer!
            //doesn't print the formatted line.
            //justifyParagraph(text,&outbuf,linelen,indentstart,indent,notFrmtLast);

            //This line directly print the buffer allocating and de-allocating
            //only a line buffer. It prints the formatted line.
            justifyParagraph(text,NULL,linelen,indentstart,indent,notFrmtLast);
            j=0;
            //To uncomment when you use the commented justifyParagraph line.
            // printf("%s\n\n",outbuf);
            puts("");
        } else {
            j+=strlen(text+j);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE * file;

    file=fopen("text.txt","r");

    formatLineByLine(file,40,5,1);
    puts("");
    formatInParagraphs(file,40,5,5,1);

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were incredibly close – but you forgot one thing!

After copying a word into `outLine`, you insert the correct number of additional spaces, and continue with 'the next word'. However, at that point the *input* pointer `i` still is at the end of the previously copied word (so it points to the first space immediately after that). The test `while (strin[i] != ' ')` then immediately fails and you insert the additional spaces at that point again. This continues until you run out of spaces to add, and at the very end you add what was not processed, which is "the entire rest of the string".

The fix is simple: after copying your word into `outLine`, copy the *original* space(s) as well, so the `i` iterator gets updated to point to the next word.

```
//One word at a time
while (endSpaces > 0 || addUnevenly > 0)
{
    //Copy letters into out
    while (strin[i] != ' ')
    {
        outLine[j] = strin[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }

    //Copy original spaces into out <-- FIX!
    while (strin[i] == ' ')
    {
        outLine[j] = strin[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
```

With this, your code works entirely as you intended. Output:

```
|Since    it    began    to    escape    from    AT&T's    Bell    Laboratories   in|
|the       early       1970's,       the       success       of       the       UNIX|
|operating        system        has        led        to        many       different|
|versions:    recipients    of    the    (at    that    time   free)   UNIX   system|
|code        all        began       developing       their       own       different|
|versions     in     their    own    different    ways    for    use    and    sale.|
|    Universities,                                                          research|
|institutes,            government           bodies           and           computer|
|companies           all          began          using         the         powerful |
|UNIX              system        to        develop        many        of        the |
|technologies          which        today        are        part        of        a |
|UNIX                system.            Computer            aided           design, |
|manufacturing   control  systems,laboratorysimulations,even   the Internet itself, |
|all        began       life       with       and       because       of       UNIX |
|Today,   without  UNIX systems, the Internewould         come to a screeching halt.|
|Most         telephone         calls        could        not        be        made,|
|electronic       commerce       would       grind      to      a      halt      and|
|there        would        have       never       been       "Jurassic       Park"! |
```

---

#### Possible improvements

Justified lines should never *begin* with whitespace (your `Copy space left of array to output` part). Just increment the pointer there:

```c
//Copy space left of array to output
while (strin[i] == ' ')
{
//  outLine[j++] = ' ';
    i++;
    endSpaces++;
}
```

(and move the calculation for `How many to add between words` below this, because it changes `endSpaces`).

The same goes for spaces at the end. You can adjust `endSpaces` at the start

```
int l = strlen(strin);
while (l > 0 && strin[l-1] == ' ')
{
    l--;
    endSpaces++;
}
```

and suppress copying the trailing spaces into `outLn` at the bottom. (That needs some additional tinkering, I couldn't get it right first time.)

It is much neater to ignore multiple spaces *inside* the input string as well, but that takes a bit more code.

With these three implemented, you get a slightly neater output:

```
|Since    it    began    to    escape    from    AT&T's    Bell    Laboratories   in|
|the       early       1970's,       the       success       of       the       UNIX|
|operating        system        has        led        to        many       different|
|versions:    recipients    of    the    (at    that    time   free)   UNIX   system|
|code        all        began       developing       their       own       different|
|versions     in     their    own    different    ways    for    use    and    sale.|
|Universities,                                                              research|
|institutes,            government           bodies           and           computer|
|companies          all          began          using          the          powerful|
|UNIX          system         to         develop         many         of         the|
|technologies         which         today         are        part        of        a|
|UNIX             system.             Computer             aided             design,|
|manufacturing   control  systems,laboratorysimulations,even  the  Internet  itself,|
|all        began        life       with       and       because       of       UNIX|
|Today,   without  UNIX  systems,  the  Internewould  come  to  a  screeching  halt.|
|Most         telephone         calls        could        not        be        made,|
|electronic       commerce       would       grind      to      a      halt      and|
|there        would        have        never       been       "Jurassic       Park"!|
```

---

A drawback of this one-line-at-a-time method is that it cannot easily be rewritten to gather input until a line overflows. To do so, you need:

1. a routine that skips all spaces and return a pointer to the *next* word.
2. a routine that reads words until a line is 'overfull' – that is, the number of words plus (the number of words - 1) for spaces is larger than your `LINE` value. This uses routine #1 and outputs exactly one justified line.

You need to pass on the location and number of strings from your `main` to both these routines, and in both check if you are at the end of either a single input line or the entire input array.

Comment: It definitely fixed and cleaned up the code! Thank you so much. You helped me get past one part of the issue but as you can see in your example at line 13 the two strings are stuck together. Is that a problem with my input file? It's a simple .txt file atm and I made sure to press enter at the end of the line so they're on two separate lines. I can't think of a reason for only that one line would not output correctly? And I can definitely see you're a typesetter, it makes me nervous replying :)

Comment: You mean the long phrase with the comma in the middle? If there should have been a return after the comma, something went wrong with saving your file. As you can see I copied your text exactly as offered. I cannot tell what went wrong in your file.

Answer (score 0):

I've written this `main` that contains two simple methods to center a text in a line. The first method only prints the `text` variable without modifying it, the second method modifies the `text` variable and then prints it. (Here method is not intended as function, the code contains two examples which you may translate easily in simple functions)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char text[81],fmt[10];
    int linelen=80,tlen;
    int spacetocenter=0;

    printf("Insert text to center [max %lu char]:\n",sizeof(text)-1);
    if (scanf("%[^\n]",text)<1) {
        perror("scanf");
        return -1;
    }
    getchar();  //Leaves return from the buffer

    tlen=strlen(text);
    spacetocenter=(linelen-tlen)/2;
    if (spacetocenter<0) 
       spacetocenter=0;

    //Method one (this doesn't modify text)
    //This method directly prints the contents of text centered.
    //----------------------------------------------------------
    snprintf(fmt,sizeof(fmt),"%%%+ds\n",spacetocenter+tlen);
    //printf("%s\n",fmt); // prints the used format
    printf(fmt,text);

    //Method two (this modifies text)
    //This method modifies the contents of the variable text
    //----------------------------------------------------------
    memmove(text+spacetocenter,text,tlen+1);
    memset(text,' ',spacetocenter);
    printf("%s\n",text);

    return 0;
}
```

Note:

- After the second method is applied `tlen` no longer contains the length of text!
- The program consider the line of 80 chars, if you need shorter/longer lines you have to modify the value of the variable `linelen`.

Comment: The question is not about centering a single line of text; it is about word-wrapping a text that is longer than one line and then adding spaces between the words so that the text is both left and right justified, like paragraphs in books.

Comment: Two minor stylistic comments: Why not use `fgets` to read a line, where you have control over the aximum length? And you can do without the intermediary format string by using the `*` as a width specifier like so: `printf("%*s, spacetocenter + tlen, text);`

Comment: @Johanatan Jensen. I've misunderstood the question ... :p

Comment: @M Oehm. I've not used fgets to avoid to modify the end of the string and to obtain a shorter code! :) I didn't know (forgotten?) the use of * in the printf. :)

Comment: @Johanatan Jensen. I like that you chose my answer as a solution to your question! but I think you wanted to choose the other answer I sent. This is the reply about the idea to center a text ... :p The functions to justify are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556416/justifying-text-in-c-and-general-array/30595329#30595329